# PHP MySql Speed optimization in 3 Level menu

Tags: php, mysql, performance, menu

I have a nicely working 3 level menu with a HUGE amount of sub-menu points. In the current test version all menu info is read from arrays in PHP and converted into $_GET parameters added to the link of a single display page. On this page the parameters submitted with $_GET are evaluated for the DB Query and the matching content will be displayed.

In order to make the content (including the corresponding menu items) modifyable by the customer, I have to move the menu structure to the database.

Now my question is:

Which is better:

a) On every update of the DB rewrite the file with menu data arrays and keep the menu as it is.

b) Generate temporary arrays of everyxthing when when the menu is displayed

c) generate the submenues only when the higher level is selected

Version a) has proven to have an acceptable page loading for end users (tested with a dummy database online) but not sure about Google ranking (depends much on page loading time). I'm not sure which is faster, reading the menu structure arrays with a MySql Query(version b) or from a file (version a). Data transmitted would be the same, so no difference in loading that.

c) has the advantage of transmitting less data in the beginning, so it would be def faster but would have to reload the page every time the end user selects a menu item. That would produce an annoying delay, which end users are usually not happy about.

Versios b) and c) would produce a lot of DB queries though,  which could be avoided with version a)

So if you have experience with speed optimization - all opinions, comments and suggestions are welcome.

Thank you,
Tina

Comment: There cannot be a HUGE amount of points in a *menu* which by design have to be comprehensible by a human, who will stop reading after first dozen.

Comment: @Tina c) generate the submenues only when the higher level is selected..here will be lots of queries but solution id optimal (in my openion) as i worked

Comment: @YourCommonSense I took that into account, that's why there is a 3-level structure.
not more than 8 in one list per level and collapsible.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I just checked the size of the generated code. (Could have had that idea earlier). It's below the size of an average 320X200 .jpg file. So I don't think that there will be any problems with transmitting the whole menu info at once. If it gets too large (it is indeed the top level of a catalog just a quite small one) I can still modify it. I doubt this will ever happen. This catalog will not grow substatially as it's not a new business.

Answer (score 1):

Menu is such a trifle matter that doesn't affect performance at all. Neither for database interaction, nor for amount of data transmitted.

If it's indeed a *menu* (Not some sort ot nested catalog with 10K+ positions) - just read all the content from database and write all at once.